# File_get_contents not evaluating to false when file does not exist

Tags: php, exception, phpunit, file-get-contents

I'm trying to test an exception in my code.

```
public function testGetFileThrowsException(){
    $this->expectException(FileNotFoundException::class);
    $file = "db.json";
    $this->review->getData($file);
}
```

The "db.json" file doesn't exist. My goal is tp have the getData() file to throw the FileNotFoundException. Here is the getData() code:

```
public function getData($path){

    if(file_get_contents($path) === false){
        throw new FileNotFoundException;
    }
    return $file;
}
```

The problem is that instead of evaluating to False and throw the exception, the file_get_contents function returns:

```
1) CompanyReviewTest::testGetFileThrowsException
file_get_contents(db.json): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

So the test doesn't run successfully. Any ideas on why does this happen?

Comment: ___Just a little point:___ `$file` does not exist in that method???? But it will if you code it as `if($file = file_get_contents($path) === false){`

Comment: 1) While debugging please remember to turn error reporting on. 2) If error reporting is on please check the error log.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about $file. Unfortunately, my goal is to test the if the exception is thrown if the $path does not exist.

Comment: Does it work if you just throw a standard `Exception`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`file_get_contents()` generates an E_WARNING level error (failed to open stream) which is what you'll want to suppress as you're already handling it with your exception class.

You can suppress this warning by adding [PHP's error control operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) `@` in front of `file_get_contents()`, example:

```
<?php

$path = 'test.php';
if (@file_get_contents($path) === false) {
    echo 'false';
    die();
}

echo 'true';

?>
```

The above echoes false, without the `@` operator it returns both the  E_WARNING and the echoed false. It may be the case that the warning error is interfering with your throw function, but without seeing the code for that it's hard to say.

Comment: But use the `@` error supressor ___very sparingly___

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 solution the poor one is to hide the error like that

```
public function getData($path){

    if(@file_get_contents($path) === false){
        throw new FileNotFoundException;
    }
    return $file;
}
```

Or check maybe if the file exist (better solution i guess)

```
public function getData($path){

if(file_exists($path) === false){
    throw new FileNotFoundException;
}
return $file;
}
```